# load page at anchor, less 175px

Tags: anchor

When loading a page from a link using an anchor (ie, website.com/#midPage), I need the anchor to actually load 175px below the top of the page. Is there a convenient way to to do this? Javascript or JQUERY is fine by me, but I don't know what method to use.

Comment: I ended up coding in a div that is 150px above the div in question, and then I link to that. It works well.